# how to change a javascript result from selectbox to textarea?

Tags: javascript, select, textarea

What I need to do I take the result from this code..

```
    function genNumbers(listbox) {
    var i, rannum;

    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    rannum = Math.random()*100000000;
    rannum = Math.round(rannum);


    if(listbox.options[i] == null) {
    listbox.options[i] = new Option( rannum + "@domain.com", rannum + "@domain.com", 0, 0 );
    } else {
    listbox.options[i].value = rannum;
    listbox.options[i].text = rannum + "@domain.com";
    }
  }
}

<form>
<select name="ranlist" size= "2"  style="width:180px"></select><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Generate Random Email" onclick="genNumbers(this.form.ranlist)";>
```

And make the result appear in a text area. What I am using this for is to generate a random email address for people that dont have an email account when we sign up people in joomla. It all works except I need the result to show in a text area/textbox so i can copy paste it out and into the email field if needed.

Any helps would be great!

Cheers
Jimmy

Answer (score 1):

Just set its `value` property:

```
textarea.value = 'foo';
```

Comment: **Don't** set the innerHTML property, set its value: `textarea.value = 'foo';`.

Comment: @RobG: *facepalm* I think I rely on jQuery a bit too much. Thanks for catching that...